# How to set up git and maven to work together?

Tags: linux, git, maven, version-control, build

I'm new to both of these tools, and I'm also very new to Linux system administration, so I apologize ahead of time for what may seem like a total n00b question.

Basically, I'm starting a whole new project from scratch.  Yaaay!  Exciting!  However, I'm a little lost on how to set up the project.  I've installed both git and maven on my dev machine and run through some tutorials.  I've also set up git on my server, and have successfully pushed code to it and pulled code from it.

So, first question : Is it even a good idea to use git and maven together?  Git seems like the best source control system, and Maven seems like the best build system.  Are they known to work well together?  Or am I needlessly creating trouble for myself at this early (and precarious) stage of the project?  I've used ant enough to know that I don't want to use it, and I'm not really a fan of svn, although I'll use it if I have to.

Second question : Given that these two tools work well together, what's the Best Practices way of setting them up?  I know that git is "peer-to-peer", although I suppose nothing is stopping you from setting up a single repository for the git user and having all the devs sync up with that repo when it's time to do a build.  Is that the right way to go?  How about Maven?  Maven seems kinda single-user oriented.  Like, everybody sets up Maven on their own machine and has their own Maven repo, right?  Or wrong?  Would it make sense to create a "Maven user" on my server, and have that user do all my builds from the "main" git repo?

Apologies if I'm totally mistaken on how to use these tools.  As I said, I'm pretty new to these things.  Any help you have is appreciated.

(also, I'm working on Linux, doing Java dev work in Eclipse, using Spring for the framework, mysql for the data store, and Hibernate as an ORM.  Don't know of any of that matters)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Yes, git will work well with any build systems. Usually your VCS is well abstracted with any modern build system. Ensure that you set up your .gitignore file so that you are not tracking any artifacts from builds.

Q2: The best practice is to have an integration branch to build from. While developing, use topic or feature branches. When ready, merge into the integration branch and push that up to the central repository where maven can build from. Google git-flow for more ideas. You generally want a central build server if you are working on a team to ensure you are building on the same machine. This is not the case if you are working alone or maybe just one developer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'm gonna be working on this tonight.  You gave me a good place to start.  Cheers!